# How does Muslim teaching on the person of Jesus differ from that of Christian teaching?

Tags: prophet-isa, christianity

Both religions acknowledge the existence of Jesus of Nazareth.  But how do the Muslim teachings about Jesus differ from the Christian view of the same person?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are the points where Islam differs with (mainstream) Christianity when it comes to the person of Jesus:

### 1. Islam does not recognize Jesus as the son of God

In Islam, Jesus is a messenger of Allah and among the five greatest known as [Ulu Al-Azm](http://www.islam-fyi.com/islamic-words/uloo-al-azm) (those of great resolve). And while he is a great and righteous man gifted with many miracles, he is not divine in any way.

> That is Jesus, the son of Mary - the word of truth about which they are in dispute. It is not [befitting] for Allah to take a son; exalted is He! When He decrees an affair, He only says to it, "Be," and it is.
>
> [(Maryam 19:34-35)](http://quran.com/19/30-35)

### 2. Islam does not teach that Jesus was crucified and reserructed

Muslims believe that Jesus did not die on the cross, but was in fact ascended up to the heavens where he continues to be alive. The majority view is that Jesus was ascended just *before* the crucifixion event and was replaced by someone else. It only *appeared* that Jesus was crucified, when in fact someone else had replaced him. There is no clear evidence on the identity of the person who replaced him, but many believe that it was Judas Iscariot.

> And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah ." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain.
>
> [(An-Nisa' 4:157)](http://quran.com/4/157)

### 3. The second coming of Jesus

Muslims believe that in the end of days, Jesus will descend again to help the [Mahdi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahdi) and the Muslims in their war against [Al-Masih Ad-Dajjal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dajjal) (the charlatan messiah). Details differ among scholars and schools of thought. See this Hadith:

> "Allah's Apostle said, "The Hour will not be established until the son of Mary (Mariam) (i.e. Isa) descends amongst you as a just ruler, he will break the cross, kill the pigs, and abolish the Jizya tax. Money will be in abundance so that nobody will accept it (as charitable gifts)."
>
> [(Sahih Bukhari 3:43:656)](http://www.cmje.org/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/043-sbt.php#003.043.656)

Comment: Christians believe in the 3rd one too. The only difference is they don't know about the Mahdi, but only the time after Jesus is back. And so they have been lead to see a Muslim public figure, say Mahdi, as the 'anti-christ' (Masih Dajjal as we know it).

Comment: @AhmetNoyanKızıltan - I know they do, but they differ on a great many things as to the nature of the second coming, which is why I added it as a separate point.

Comment: I confirm that the answer above is accurate from an Islamic perspective. Just in case anyone ever wonders whether the votes up are just because it is a “nice” answer, or also because it is correct and accurate.

Comment: @system down Mahdi will help eesa not other way around if you are sunni. Eesa will be caliph starting immediately after fajr prayer

Answer (score 8):

In Islam, We believe Jesus is a Prophet, Messenger of Allah, Spirit of Allah, Word of Allah .

> O people of the Scripture (Jews and Christians)! Do not exceed the
>   limits in your religion, nor say of Allaah aught but the truth. The
>   Messiah Eesaa (Jesus), son of Maryam (Mary), was (no more than) a
>   Messenger of Allaah and His Word (through which He created him), (a
>   Word) which He bestowed on Maryam (Mary) and a spirit (Rooh) created
>   by Him. So believe in Allaah and His Messengers. Say not: "Three
>   (trinity)!" Cease! (it is) better for you. For Allaah is (the only)
>   God (worthy of worship), Glory be to Him (Far Exalted is He) above
>   having a son. To Him belongs all that is in the heavens and all that
>   is in the earth. And Allah is All-Sufficient as a Disposer of affairs.
>   (An-Nisa 4:171)

This verse was revealed in relation to various factions of the Christians (Ya'qubiyyah, Nestoriyyah, Malikaaniyyah, Marqoosiyyah), and they had various sayings so some said, "Jesus is Allaah", others said, "He is the son of Allaah" and others said, "He is the third of three." Source: [Jesus in Islam](http://www.islamjesus.ws/articles/eisoz-jesus-is-the-messenger-the-word-and-the-spirit-of-allaah-the-exalted.cfm)

And he is the blessed Messiah and no more than a Messenger. He was humble servant and worshipper of Allah.

> The Messiah (Jesus, son of Mary) was no more than a Messenger, many
>   were the Messengers that passed away before him. His mother (Mary) was
>   a Siddeeqah (she believed in the words of Allaah and his Books). They
>   both used to eat food [as other human beings do while Allaah does not
>   eat]. Look at how We make the signs clear to them, yet look at how
>   they are deluded from the Truth. (5:75)

Moreover, Christians believe Jesus is dead. But, we believe that Jesus is alive and he will return upon earth at the appointed time near the approach of the Hour when he will kill al-Dajjaal (the great liar), and he will abide by and establish Islaam, and there will be none from the people of the book (Jews, Christians) except that they will affirm their faith in him and his essential message of Islam.

> Then she pointed to him (the baby, Jesus). They said: ‘How can we talk
>   to one who is a child in the cradle?’ He (Jesus) said: ‘Verily I am a
>   slave of God, He has given me the Scripture and made me a Prophet; And
>   He has made me blessed wheresoever I may be, and has enjoined on me
>   prayer, and Zakaat (charity), as long as I live.  And dutiful to my
>   mother, and did not make me arrogant, unblest.  And Salaam (peace) be
>   upon me the day I was born, and the day that I die, and the day I
>   shall be raised alive!’” [19:29-33]

More subtle differences in belief:

Both Christians and Muslims believe that Jesus could perform miracles. But, Christians believe it was his own power but Muslims believe it was through the power given by Allah.

Comment: There are many differences. Maybe should we all merge our answers into one.

Comment: @Atif I agree. But don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Atif It is actually a GOOD thing that there was not one right answer. There were many.

Comment: @Dynamic There is a lot of repetition of points, and as a programmer that bothers me :)

Comment: @Atif - DRY? lol

Comment: @SystemDown exactly!

Comment: "Christians believe Jesus is dead." That is incorrect. Christianity exists because Christians believe that Jesus was killed then *resurrected*. Christians, therefore, believe He is alive.

Comment: @fredsbend The belief of Muslims with respect to Jesus is that he was not killed. Every person in this world will be dead and then resurrected. That doesn't mean you are not dead. You are dead with respect to this world. The point is, the belief of Christians and Muslims is different with respect to death (or killing) of Jesus (Whatever you wish to call it)

Answer (score 5):

Christians believe that Jesus was crucified

Muslims do not, We believe that He ascended

> وَقَوۡلِهِمۡ إِنَّا قَتَلۡنَا ٱلۡمَسِيحَ عِيسَى ٱبۡنَ مَرۡيَمَ رَسُولَ ٱللَّهِ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ وَمَا صَلَبُوهُ وَلَـٰكِن شُبِّهَ لَهُمۡ‌ۚ وَإِنَّ ٱلَّذِينَ ٱخۡتَلَفُواْ فِيهِ لَفِى شَكٍّ۬ مِّنۡهُ‌ۚ مَا لَهُم بِهِۦ مِنۡ عِلۡمٍ إِلَّا ٱتِّبَاعَ ٱلظَّنِّ‌ۚ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ يَقِينَۢا (١٥٧) بَل رَّفَعَهُ ٱللَّهُ إِلَيۡهِ‌ۚ وَكَانَ ٱللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمً۬ا (١٥٨)
>
> That they said (in boast), "We killed Christ Jesus the son of Mary, the Messenger of Allah";― but they killed him not, nor crucified him, but so it was made to appear to them and those who differ therein are full of doubts, with no (certain) knowledge, but only conjecture to follow, for of a surety they killed him not.― (157)

Surat 4 Ayah 157

Christians believe that He is the son of Allah, and sometimes Allah Himself, Auzubillah.

Muslims believe that He is a Prophet of Allah

> إِذۡ قَالَتِ ٱلۡمَلَـٰٓٮِٕكَةُ يَـٰمَرۡيَمُ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يُبَشِّرُكِ بِكَلِمَةٍ۬ مِّنۡهُ ٱسۡمُهُ ٱلۡمَسِيحُ عِيسَى ٱبۡنُ مَرۡيَمَ وَجِيهً۬ا فِى ٱلدُّنۡيَا وَٱلۡأَخِرَةِ وَمِنَ ٱلۡمُقَرَّبِينَ (٤٥)
>
> Behold! the angels said "O Mary! Allah giveth thee glad tidings of a Word from Him: his name will be Christ Jesus, the son of Mary held in honour in this world and the Hereafter and of (the company of) those nearest to Allah. (45)

Surat 3 Ayah 45

> مَّا ٱلۡمَسِيحُ ٱبۡنُ مَرۡيَمَ إِلَّا رَسُولٌ۬ قَدۡ خَلَتۡ مِن قَبۡلِهِ ٱلرُّسُلُ وَأُمُّهُ ۥ صِدِّيقَةٌ۬‌ۖ ڪَانَا يَأۡڪُلَانِ ٱلطَّعَامَ‌ۗ ٱنظُرۡ ڪَيۡفَ نُبَيِّنُ لَهُمُ ٱلۡأَيَـٰتِ ثُمَّ ٱنظُرۡ أَنَّىٰ يُؤۡفَكُونَ (٧٥)
>
> Christ the son of Mary was no more than an Messenger; many were the Messengers that passed away before him. His mother was a woman of truth. They had both to eat their (daily) food. See how Allah doth makes His Signs clear to them; yet see in what ways they are deluded away from the truth! (75)

Surat 5 Ayah 75

Answer (score 1):

In the Qur'an, in a passage describing the annunciation to the Blessed Virgin Mary, Jesus ('a) is described as a Word from God: "O Mary! Verily Allah gives you the glad tidings of a Word from Him; his name is the Messiah, Jesus son of Mary, eminent in this world, and in the Hereafter of those near [to God]" (3:44)

The context in which this ayah was revealed was one of inter-religious encounter. It is said that the Christians of Najran sent a delegation to the Prophet of Islam (s) at Makkah to question him about the teachings of Islam concerning Jesus ('a), and God revealed the above and other ayat of Surat Al 'Imran in response. The response is not only not a denial of Christian teachings, although the divinity of Christ is clearly rejected, but also an affirmation of much believed by Christians as well, even the designation of Christ as logos: 'O People of the Book! Do not go to extremes in your creed, and do not say of Allah but the Truth. Verily, the Messiah, Jesus the son of Mary, is only an apostle of Allah and His Word which He conveyed unto Mary, and a Spirit from Him (Qur'an 4:171) So in addition to being called the Word of God, Jesus ('a) is also called a Spirit of God and in some of the narrations reported in the Shi'i tradition, this title is used.

Please look at these two:

http://www.al-islam.org/al-tawhid/jesus.htm

http://www.al-islam.org/jesus_shiite_narrations/